# discord.py channel.history returning [] from working channel and time

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to scan all messages from this but I can't figure out why this keeps outputting []

```
#in this case 2021-01-01 00:00:00 
start_of_month = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
#in this case 2021-01-31 23:59:59 
end_of_month = self.last_second_of_month(start_of_month)   
            
channel = self.bot.get_channel(channelIdgoeshere)

messages = await channel.history(before=start_of_month, after=end_of_month).flatten()
```

I have legitimate and working id in place of "channelIdgoeshere"

edit: I had times mixed up

Comment: You inverted the `before` and `after` arguments in the `channel.history` call, creating an impossible to fulfil condition.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for answering, this didn't fix the problem though